# The right word to show honour for president or such dignitaries while addressing them

Tags: word-choice, politeness, interpersonal-relations

what is the right word to show honour while addressing president or such dignitaries. Is "respected president" sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

The “right” **form of address** depends largely on the country you are in, rather than the language that is spoken.

In the past, especially nobility and clergy where addressed with prescribed honorary titles. This [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forms_of_address_in_the_United_Kingdom) page gives you some idea about forms address in the UK, for example. Note that there are different forms of address when you *write* to them or when you *speak* to them, and you sometimes use yet another form when *referring* to them.

You do not specify *which* president you refer to, so I cannot be sure of the “correct” answer, but if you mean the president of the US, you can call him *Mr. President*. More details can be found here, on [formsofaddress](http://www.formsofaddress.info/FOA_president_US.html).
For obvious reasons, *mr. president* will not be acceptable when addressing the president of, say, Brazil or Kosovo.

Answer (score 1):

If you are **speaking to the dignitary directly,** then "Sir" or "Ma'am" (for "Madam") as appropriate will usually be acceptable to anyone.

There may be other protocols. For example, when addressing a member of the British Royal Family, one is supposed to use the formal title the first time, "Good morning, Your Majesty," and then revert to an ordinary form after that: "Another teacake, Ma'am?"

This would also work for other dignitaries. Use their title first: "Good morning, Mr President; Good morning, Your Excellency," and then follow with "Sir" or "Ma'am" as appropriate.

How you address the dignitary in the first instance is entirely dependent on who that person is. "Mr President" may well work; ambassadors are usually "Your Excellency". There is no general rule.

Comment: 'Your Unspeakableness' is rarely used.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth However "Your Ineffability" appears in places, which might serve much the same purpose.

Comment: You may well say that. I could not possibly comment.

Comment: If Hillary becomes President will she be *Madam President*, or *Ma'am President*?